# how to cast nvarchar to int then add in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i do not understand that what wrong in this query

```
select cast(B1 as int)+
       (cast(H1 as int)+
       (cast(C1 as int)+
       (cast(I1 as int)) as [man] 
From Kanpur
```

`B1, H1, C1, I1` is declared as nvarchar in database

```
error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Comment: Your parens don't balance.  You need a final three closing parens.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing parantheses.

```
select (cast(B1 as int)+cast(H1 as int)+cast(C1 as int)+cast(I1 as int)) as [man]
From Kanpur
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing parenthesis...write as:

```
select cast(B1 as int)+
       (cast(H1 as int))+
       (cast(C1 as int))+
       (cast(I1 as int)) as [man] 
From Kanpur
```